# Calculating plumb-bob coefficients from rational-polynomial coefficients for camera lense distortion

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, polynomial-math

Is it possible to recalculate the plumb-bob coefficients for a given OpenCV calibration file, that was created using a rational-polynomial model?
Concerning [group__calib3d.html](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html), the plumb-bob model uses the coefficients `[k1, k2, p1, p2, k3]` while the rational-polynomial model uses `[k1, k2, p1, p2, k3, k4, k5, k6]`.
The distortion model looks like

[image: distortion model]

Thus, the rational-polynomial model just adds a denominator in the first term.
Do I have to refit the plumb-bob into the rational polynom, or is there some easier approach to get `[k1, k2, p1, p2, k3]`?

Here is an example of the rational-polynomial coefficient: `[0.452407000, 0.273748000, -0.000110000, 0.000152000, 0.027904000, 0.817958000, 0.358389000, 0.108657000]`